# Bluetooth tethering and WiFi hot spot

Tags: bluetooth

I am using bluetooth tethering through my one android phone to another android phone and i am using free VPN app on my second android phone which is connected by bluetooth tethering to open Facebook because it's blocked.

I am using my company's WiFi network to connect to internet. Can IT department of the company trace that i am using bluetooth tethering on my second android phone through my first android phone and using Facebook?

Comment: which phone? is the phone owned by the company or have they installed management software on it?

Answer (score 1):

They can't see that you're using Facebook, but they can see that you have an encrypted connection coming out of your phone. All the Bluetooth tethering is doing is forwarding packets from one phone to the internet, if you're tethering to a cellular network your company won't be able to see what your doing. However if you're tethering to their corporate wifi, they're going to see a VPN connection coming from your device, but the contents will be encrypted.

I'd recommend you simply stay off of Facebook and not try to get around the block. A rogue VPN connection in a corporate network is troublesome, Your IT department won't be able to know what you're doing on the VPN, for all they know you're either browsing Facebook or leaking sensitive information.